# How to convert JSON data to tidy format in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I never have worked with json data in R and unfortunately, I was sent a sample of data as:

```r
{
  "task_id": "104",
  "status": "succeeded",
  "metrics": {
    "requests_made": 2,
    "network_errors": 0,
    "unique_locations_visited": 0,
    "requests_queued": 0,
    "queue_items_completed": 2,
    "queue_items_waiting": 0,
    "issue_events": 9,
    "caption": "",
    "progress": 100
  },
  "message": "",
  "issue_events": [
    {
      "id": "1234",
      "type": "issue_found",
      "issue": {
        "name": "policy not enforced",
        "type_index": 123456789,
        "serial_number": "123456789183923712",
        "origin": "https://test.com",
        "path": "/robots.txt",
        "severity": "low",
        "confidence": "certain",
        "caption": "/robots.txt",
        "evidence": [
          {
            "type": "FirstOrderEvidence",
            "detail": {
              "band_flags": [
                "in_band"
              ]
            },
            "request_response": {
              "url": "https://test.com/robots.txt",
              "request": [
                {
                  "type": "DataSegment",
                  "data": "jaghsdjgasdgaskjdgasdgashdgsahdgasjkdgh==",
                  "length": 313
                }
              ],
              "response": [
                {
                  "type": "DataSegment",
                  "data": "asudasjdgasaaasgdasgaksjdhgasjdgkjghKGKGgKJgKJgKJGKgh==",
                  "length": 303
                }
              ],
              "was_redirect_followed": false,
              "request_time": "1234567890"
            }
          }
        ],
        "internal_data": "jdfhgjhJHkjhdskfhkjhjs0sajkdfhKHKhkj=="
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "1235",
      "type": "issue_found",
      "issue": {
        "name": "certificate",
        "type_index": 12345845684,
        "serial_number": "123456789165637150",
        "origin": "https://test.com",
        "path": "/",
        "severity": "info",
        "confidence": "certain",
        "description": "The server description a valid, trusted certificate. This issue is purely informational.<br><br>The server presented the following certificates:<br><br><h4>Server certificate</h4><table><tr><td><b>Issued to:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>test.ie, test.com, www.test.com, www.test.ie</td></tr><tr><td><b>Issued by:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>GeoTrust EV RSA CA 2018</td></tr><tr><td><b>Valid from:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Tue May 12 00:00:00 UTC 2020</td></tr><tr><td><b>Valid to:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Tue May 17 12:00:00 UTC 2022</td></tr></table><h4>Certificate chain #1</h4><table><tr><td><b>Issued to:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>GeoTrust EV RSA CA 2018</td></tr><tr><td><b>Issued by:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td> High Assurance EV Root CA</td></tr><tr><td><b>Valid from:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Mon Nov 06 12:22:46 UTC 2017</td></tr><tr><td><b>Valid to:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Sat Nov 06 12:22:46 UTC 2027</td></tr></table><h4>Certificate chain #2</h4><table><tr><td><b>Issued to:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td> High Assurance EV Root CA</td></tr><tr><td><b>Issued by:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td> High Assurance EV Root CA</td></tr><tr><td><b>Valid from:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Fri Nov 10 00:00:00 UTC 2006</td></tr><tr><td><b>Valid to:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>Mon Nov 10 00:00:00 UTC 2031</td></tr></table>",
        "caption": "/",
        "evidence": [],
        "internal_data": "sjhdgsajdggJGJHgjfgjhGJHgjhsdgfgjhGJHGjhsdgfjhsgfdsjfg098867hjhgJHGJHG=="
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "1236",
      "type": "issue_found",
      "issue": {
        "name": "without flag set",
        "type_index": 1254392,
        "serial_number": "12345678965616",
        "origin": "https://test.com",
        "path": "/robots.txt",
        "severity": "info",
        "confidence": "certain",
        "description": "my description text here....",
        "caption": "/robots.txt",
        "evidence": [
          {
            "type": "InformationListEvidence",
            "request_response": {
              "url": "https://test.com/robots.txt",
              "request": [
                {
                  "type": "DataSegment",
                  "data": "adjkhajksdhaskjdhkjHKJHjkhaskjdhkjasdhKHKJHkjsdhfkjsdhfkjsdhKHJKHjksdfhsdjkfhksdjhKHKJHJKhsdkfjhsdkfjhKHJKHjksdkfjhsdkjfhKHKJHjkhsdkfjhsdkjfhsdjkfhksdjfhKJHKjksdhfsdjkfhksdjfhsdkjhKHJKhsdkfhsdkjfhsdkfhdskjhKHKjhsdfkjhsdjkfh==",
                  "length": 313
                }
              ],
              "response": [
                {
                  "type": "DataSegment",
                  "data": "adjkhajksdhaskjdhkjHKJHjkhaskjdhkjasdhKHKJHkjsdhfkjsdhfkjsdhKHJKHjksdfhsdjkfhksdjhKHKJHJKhsdkfjhsdkfjhKHJKHjksdkfjhsdkjfhKHKJHjkhsdkfjhsdkjfhsdjkfhksdjfhKJHKjksdhfsdjkfhksdjfhsdkjhKHJKhsdkfhsdkjfhsdkfhdskjhKHKjhsdfkjhsdjkfh=",
                  "length": 161
                },
                {
                  "type": "HighlightSegment",
                  "data": "adjkhajksdhaskjdhkjHKJHjkhaskjdhkjasdhKHKJHkjsdhfkjsdhfkjsdhKHJKHjksdfhsdjkfhksdjhKHKJHJKhsdkfjhsdkfjhKHJKHjksdkfjhsdkjfhKHKJHjkhsdkfjhsdkjfhsdjkfhksdjfhKJHKjksdhfsdjkfhksdjfhsdkjhKHJKhsdkfhsdkjfhsdkfhdskjhKHKjhsdf=",
                  "length": 119
                },
                {
                  "type": "DataSegment",
                  "data": "AasjkdhasjkhkjHKJSDHFJKSDFHKhjkHSKADJFHKhjkhjkh=",
                  "length": 23
                }
              ],
              "was_redirect_followed": false,
              "request_time": "178454751191465"
            },
            "information_items": [
              "Other: user_id"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "internal_data": "adjkhajksdhaskjdhkjHKJHjkhaskjdhkjasdhKHKJHkjsdhfkjsdhfkjsdhKHJKHjksdfhsdjkfhksdjhKHKJHJKhsdkfjhsdkfjhKHJKHjksdkfjhsdkjfhKHKJHjkhsdkfjhsdkjfhsdjkfhksdjfhKJHKjksdhfsdjkfhksdjfhsdkjhKHJKhsdkfhsdkjfhsdkfhdskjhKH=="
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "1237",
      "type": "issue_found",
      "issue": {
        "name": "without flag set",
        "type_index": 1234567,
        "serial_number": "123456789056704",
        "origin": "https://test.com",
        "path": "/",
        "severity": "info",
        "confidence": "certain",
        "description": "long description here zjkhasdjkh hsajkdhsajkd hasjkdhbsjkdash d",
        "caption": "/",
        "evidence": [
          {
            "type": "InformationListEvidence",
            "request_response": {
              "url": "https://test.com/",
              "request": [
                {
                  "type": "DataSegment",
                  "data": "adjkhajksdhaskjdhkjHKJHjkhaskjdhkjasdhKHKJHkjsdhfkjsdhfkjsdhKHJKHjksdfhsdjkfhksdjhKHKJHJKhsdkfjhsdkfjhKHJKHjksdkfjhsdkjfhKHKJHjkhsdkfjhsdkjfhsdjkfhksdjfhKJHKjksdhfsdjkfhksdjfhsdkjhKHJKhsdkfhsdkjfhsdkfhdskjhKHKjhsdfkjhsdjkfhsfdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfsdfdsf",
                  "length": 303
                }
              ],
              "response": [
                {
                  "type": "DataSegment",
                  "data": "adjkhajksdhaskjdhkjHKJHjkhaskjdhkjasdhKHKJHkjsdhfkjsdhfkjsdhKHJKHjksdfhsdjkfhksdjhKHKJHJKhsdkfjhsdkfjhKHJKHjksdkfjhsdkjfhKHKJHjkhsdkfjhsdkjfhsdjkfhksdjfhKJHKjksdhfsdjkfhksdjfhsdkjhKHJKhsdkfhsdkjfhsdkfhdskjhKHKjhsdfkjhsdjkfh==",
                  "length": 151
                },
                {
                  "type": "HighlightSegment",
                  "data": "adjkhajksdhaskjdhkjHKJHjkhaskjdhkjasdhKHKJHkjsdhfkjsdhfkjsdhKHJKHjksdfhsdjkfhksdjhKHKJHJKhsdkfjhsdkfjhKHJKHjksdkfjhsdkjfhKHKJHjkhsdkfjhsdkjfhsdjkfhksdjfhKJHKjksdhfsdjkfhksdjfhsdkjhKHJKhsdkfhsdkjfhsdkfhdskjhKHKjhsdfkjhsdjkfh=",
                  "length": 119
                },
                {
                  "type": "DataSegment",
                  "data": "sdfdsfsdfSDFSDFdSFDS546SDFSDFDSFG657=",
                  "length": 23
                }
              ],
              "was_redirect_followed": false,
              "request_time": "123541191466"
            },
            "information_items": [
              "Other: user_id"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "internal_data": "adjkhajksdhaskjdhkjHKJHjkhaskjdhkjasdhKHKJHkjsdhfkjsdhfkjsdhKHJKHjksdfhsdjkfhksdjhKHKJHJKhsdkfjhsdkfjhKHJKHjksdkfjhsdkjfhKHKJHjkhsdkfjhsdkjfhsdjkfhksdjfhKJHKjksdhfsdjkfhksdjfhsd=="
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "1238",
      "type": "issue_found",
      "issue": {
        "name": "parameter pollution",
        "type_index": 4137000,
        "serial_number": "123456789810290176",
        "origin": "https://test.com",
        "path": "/robots.txt",
        "severity": "low",
        "confidence": "firm",
        "description": "very long description text here...",
        "caption": "/robots.txt [URL path filename]",
        "evidence": [
          {
            "type": "FirstOrderEvidence",
            "detail": {
              "payload": {
                "bytes": "Q3jkeiZkcmg8MQ==",
                "flags": 0
              },
              "band_flags": [
                "in_band"
              ]
            },
            "request_response": {
              "url": "https://test.com/%3fhdz%26drh%3d1",
              "request": [
                {
                  "type": "DataSegment",
                  "data": "W1QOIC8=",
                  "length": 5
                },
                {
                  "type": "HighlightSegment",
                  "data": "WRMnBGR6JTI2ZHJoJTNkMQ==",
                  "length": 16
                },
                {
                  "type": "DataSegment",
                  "data": "adjkhajksdhaskjdhkjHKJHjkhaskjdhkjasdhKHKJHkjsdhfkjsdhfkjsdhKHJKHjksdfhsdjkfhksdjhKHKJHJKhsdkfjhsdkfjhKHJKHjksdkfjhsdkjfhKHKJHjkhsdkfjhsdkjfhsdjkfhksdjfhKJHKjksdhfsdjkfhksdjfhsdkjhKHJKhsdkfhsdkjfhsdkfhdskjhKHKjhsdfkjhsdjkfhcvxxcvklxcvjkxclvjxclkvjxcklvjlxckjvlxckjvklxcjvxcklvjxcklvjxckljvlxckjvxcklvjxckljvxcklvjcklxjvcxkl==",
                  "length": 298
                }
              ],
              "response": [
                {
                  "type": "DataSegment",
                  "data": "adjkhajksdhaskjdhkjHKJHjkhaskjdhkjasdhKHKJHkjsdhfkjsdhfkjsdhKHJKHjksdfhsdjkfhksdjhKHKJHJKhsdkfjhsdkfjhKHJKHjksdkfjhsdkjfhKHKJHjkhsdkfjhsdkjfhsdjkfhksdjfhKJHKjksdhfsdjkfhksdjfhsdkjhKHJKhsdkfhsdkjfhsdkfhdskjhKHKjhsdfkjhsdjkfh==",
                  "length": 130
                },
                {
                  "type": "HighlightSegment",
                  "data": "Q4jleiZkcmg9MQ==",
                  "length": 10
                },
                {
                  "type": "DataSegment",
                  "data": "adjkhajksdhaskjdhkjHKJHjkhaskjdhkjasdhKHKJHkjsdhfkjsdhfkjsdhKHJKHjksdfhsdjkfhksdjhKHKJHJKhsdkfjhsdkfjhKHJKHjksdkfjhsdkjfhKHKJHjkhsdkfjhsdkjfhsdjkfhksdjfhKJHKjksdhfsdjkfhksdjfhsdkjhKHJKhsdkfhsdkjfhsdkfhdskjhKHKjhsdfkjhsdjkfh==",
                  "length": 163
                }
              ],
              "was_redirect_followed": false,
              "request_time": "51"
            }
          }
        ],
        "internal_data": "adjkhajksdhaskjdhkjHKJHjkhaskjdhkjasdhKHKJHkjsdhfkjsdhfkjsdhKHJKHjksdfhsdjkfhksdjhKHKJHJKhsdkfjhsdkfjhKHJKHjksdkfjhsdkjfhKHKJHjkhsdkfjhsdkjfhsdjkfhksdjfhKJHKjksdhfsdjkfhksdjfhsdkjhKHJKhsdkfhsdkjfhsdkfhdskjhKHKjhsdfkjhsdjkfh="
      }
    }
  ],
  "event_logs": [],
  "audit_items": []
}
```

I read it in R using `jsonlite`:

```r
df_orig <- fromJSON('dast_sample_output.json', flatten= T)
```

This gives a nested `list` type R object. I wish to convert this list to a `data frame` in a `tidy format` with all the arrays and sub arrays being unnested.
If you run the `str(df_orig)`, you could see the nested data frames in there.

How do I convert it to tidy format?
I tried `unnest()`, `purrr` but struggling to get into the tidy format for analysis? Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Cheers,

Comment: Please share a `dput` of `df_orig` and your expected output.

Comment: Hi, sorry due to the sensitivity of the data, i cant `dput`, you could simply copy paste the data and read it in using `jsonlite`

Comment: I can't copy and paste your code, it creates some errors: `Error: parse error: premature EOF` or `Error: parse error: after array element` if I add an `}` to the end. If you are showing this code, you can `dput` this example data without any thoughts to the sensitivity. You showed the data already.

Comment: Sorry, I just fixed the data.

Comment: Please post the example of your desired output.

Comment: @PeteKittinun I have added some info but if you read the data in, and run the str() method you could see there are multiple levels of nested data frames. I want to unnest the whole dataset

Answer (score -2):

use the `jsonlite` package function `fromJSON()`

edit:

set option `flatten=T`

edit2:

use `content( x, 'text')` before flattening

here is a full example converting to data.table:

```
get.json <- GET( apicall.text )
get.json.text <- content( get.json , 'text')
get.json.flat <- fromJSON( get.json.text , flatten = T)
dt <- as.data.table( get.json.flat )
```

Comment: thats what i did. It's in my question but it doesnt put it in a tidy format

Comment: set option flatten=T

Comment: I did but it doesnt unnest the data. You could try with the example data and check it has multiple `[]` etc.

Comment: I use content( x , 'text') before fromJSON()